# Where are stored the group prices on magento database?

Tags: product, backend, database, products-management

I'm developing a module in backend that displays the 'group prices' of the products, but I don't know where are them stored in the database in order to show them. If anyone has some idea I will appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, displaying the price of a grouped product is trivial:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
echo $product->getPrice();
```

Secondly, where it is stored and how it is calculated is not so much complex as it is undesirable. Accessing the database directly for pricing will not respect the custom options related to pricing that are set on the backend:

- Display price before tax
- Display "as low as" for configurables
- Display in alternate currencies based on store view language config

So I suggest you not do this in your module. However for purely academic reasons, all pricing can be found for a product in one of two ways:

**If you're using flat catalog**

`SELECT sku, price from catalog_product_flat_1 where sku='[your_grouped_sku]';`

*Note: the last `_1` of the table name is generally the internal id of the store view code.*

**If you're not using flat catalog**

This gets tricky because your eav attribute id for base pricing may be different than mine - Mine are entity_type_id = 4, attribute_id=64. Make sure to look yours up via `attribute_code` in `eav_attribute` table:

```
SELECT sku, price.value AS price
FROM catalog_product_entity 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal price ON (price.`entity_type_id`=4) AND (price.`attribute_id`=64)
WHERE sku='[your sku]'
```

**How you *should* be doing this**

Use a custom collection that extends an existing collection - joining on your custom table. Because you haven't provided any direction here this is intended to be pseudo-code that will point you in the right direction. This is in no way complete and is not a drop-in fix to provide your own collection.

```
<?php

class YourCompany_Module_Model_Feature_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

        $your_table = $this->getTable('yourmodule/model');

        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(array('a'=>$your_table),'a.entity_id=main_table.entity_id');

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

For more on creating and working with custom collections see these articles:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm

http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections

Comment: I will underline here: DON'T ACCESS THE DATABASE DIRECTLY(!) :-)

Comment: ***DON'T ACCESS THE DATABASE*** - there. I think it's clear :)

Comment: It can not be mentioned enough ;)

Comment: Why ? I have some functionalities on my magento website with new tables on the database made by me. Anyway, Thanks @philwinkle for the extended answer! :)

Comment: You an perform a join to your custom table using Magento's ORM without writing any SQL. I will give you some direction in the answer.

Comment: @inavas Magento developer shy away from using RAW SQL to access the database because, in the past, Magento has changed how certain items are stored in the database, or you may thing you're reading the data from the correct place, but you're actually not.

Comment: Your mysql request seems incorrect for me. Not only the attribute_id should be retrieved from the eav_attribute table (in my case the id for the special_price attribute is not 64 but 76), but your join also lacks for some restriction on both the product entity_id and the store_id.

Comment: @MacRicow if you care to elaborate in an answer of your own it may make more sense. This is a 3 year old question and it's hard to follow the context of your comment.